# How to convert a REBOL script into an EXE?

Tags: exe, rebol

How do I create a windows executable (.exe) from a REBOL Script?
Are there any instructions or videos?

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to do that?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way with Rebol 2 is to use the SDK - though that costs money for a license. The method is called **encapping**.

There is a free encapper for Rebol 3 - though it only works on a specific version of R3.

http://r3al.org/rebol3-encapper.html

If you use RED, the .exe comes almost as standard:

http://www.red-lang.org/p/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

Other wrapper tools can be used as well. I have used the NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) in the past with great success. They even have an example (Rebol 2)

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_to_turn_a_REBOL_script_into_EXE

Comment: Thank you Johnk.  Best wishes from Zabo